# Sort jcl replace all

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I've got a very interesting question. Using inrec parse I delete delimiter(.), and replace it by 20 spaces. May I change 20 spaces by comma using jcl and sort (or icetool)?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, you could change 20 spaces to a comma. If it is the same 20 spaces, why not just change the full-stop/period/point to a comma and forget about the spaces?

Comment: How do you know the question is interesting? What message did it give you?